# JS as a regular string

Tags: javascript, string

If you do

```js
alert("\fan")
```

It doesn't print `\fan`. How do I make it so it prints it?

PS: This is like `r"\fan"` in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript version of `r"..."` is [`` String.raw`...` ``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) :

```js
alert(String.raw`\fan`)
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is used to escape special characters. If you want to use a literal backslash, a double backslash has to be used.

```js
alert("\\fan")
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to escape the `\` character with `\\`.

```js
alert("\\fan")
```